# Manually selecting web page radio button

Tags: c#

i want to programatically select a radio button in code. The radio button lives on an internal webpage.

I am trying so far like this,

```
HtmlElement rButton = b.Document.GetElementById("nameOfButton)
```

which i assume gets me a handle on the radio button, but i cant find a `.selected = true` or something similar. I need to do this because on the page, when this button is selected more values appear on the page which i then need to fill out.

edit: i think i have managed to do this using

`rButton.invokemMemeber("click")` - however i think i am still going down a cul de sac with this one.

i would like to add, i think that the page is using postback. if i click the radio button, a set of new options on the page appears, its one of these dynamically created text boxes i need a handle on. is this going to be impossible to get?

Comment: Seems like you need some sort of client side javascript to do this. JQuery is a nice library that you can use to do these kinds of stuff. I am sure there are others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do,

```
 var rButton = b.Document.GetElementById("nameOfButton"); 
    if(rButton != null)
         rButton.checked=true;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: sorry to pee you off! i managed the click event using, rbutton.invokemember("click") though i am not sure if any of this is going to help in the grand scheme of things, could you please see my edit.

Comment: I have seen your edit but it doesnt contain any thing like rbutton.invokemember("click"). You can select a radio button by javascript, I have puit that code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
if (doc.GetElementById("nameOfButton") != null)
            doc.GetElementById("nameOfButton").SetAttribute("checked", "true");
```

Good luck!